# How docker implements filesystem level isolation？

Tags: docker, chroot

I'm trying to find out how docker implements filesystem level isolation, I've done some reading about how container isolate filesystem like https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/container-security/9781492056690/ch04.html, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fi7uSYlOdc, both of them tell me that container typically use `chroot` to achieve filesystem level isolation. When I try to use the `strace` tool to detect the syscalls used by `docker run`, I don't find the chroot syscall, this confuses me.

The entire strace command I use is `strace -f -o result.txt docker run --rm -it ubuntu bash`, I find syscall used by `docker run` in `result.txt`, I search the whole file but cann't find `chroot` syscall

My questions are:

1. whether this problem is caused by `strace`, `strace` can't trace syscall in container so `chroot` is omitted， if it is, what else methods can I use to detect `chroot` syscall?
2. If `chroot` really isn't being used in `docker run`, What mechanism does docker use to achieve filesystem isolation?

Comment: Containers do **not** use `chroot` for isolation; they use a number of Linux [namespaces](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/building-container-namespaces): a `mount` namespace for filesystem isolation, a `network` namespace for network isolation, a `pid` namespace for process id isolation, etc.

Comment: sorry for my poor knowledge, I follow your comment and find that docker use `pivot_root` to change the root, but I still cann't use `strace` to trace this syscall, I switch to use `perf` to trace and finally find observe this syscall, thanks : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> tool to detect the syscalls used by docker run

Docker is a client server application. All docker cli does is it sends requests to docker deamon. Docker deamon does all the work. You have to stop docker deamon and run dockerd inside strace and then you will see `chroot` and `pivot_root` system calls.

Here I run a docker-in-docker for testing, because I do not want to touch my host docker deamon, do run a strace dockerd command and then run a alpine image. I filter with grep because I am lazy. You can see `pivot_root("/var/lib/docker/overlay2..."` syscall made by dockerd.

```
# docker run -ti --rm --privileged --entrypoint= docker:dind sh -l
   // inside docker:dind container:
0592bac28743:/# apk add strace 
...
0592bac28743:/# strace dockerd 2> >(grep pivot_root) &
   // wait a bit for dockerd to start
   // and finally:
0592bac28743:/# docker run -ti --rm alpine echo 1
Unable to find image 'alpine:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
7264a8db6415: Extracting [>                                                  ]  65.54kB/3.402MB
[pid    28] mkdirat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b744b0e22645db69ca63c6a68ed671d54ead252088fd74b2867b01efd88adad9/diff/.pivot_root27393485", 0700) = 0
[pid    28] pivot_root("/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b744b0e22645db69ca63c6a68ed671d54ead252088fd74b2867b01efd88adad9/diff", "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b744b0e22645db69ca63c6a68ed671d54ead252088fd74b2867b01efd88adad9/diff/.pivot_root27393485") = 0
[pid    28] mount("", "/.pivot_root27393485", 0xc001025bb3, MS_REC|MS_PRIVATE, NULL) = 0
[pid    28] umount2("/.pivot_root27393485", MNT_DETACH) = 0
[pid    28] unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "/.pivot_root27393485", 0) = -1 EISDIR (Is a directory)
7264a8db6415: Extracting [==================================================>]  3.402MB/3.402MB
[pid    28] newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/sbin/pivot_root", 0xc00072bbd8, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid    28] symlinkat("/bin/busybox", AT_FDCWD, "/sbin/pivot_root") = 0
[pid    28] fchownat(AT_FDCWD, "/sbin/pivot_root", 0, 0, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
[pid    28] utimensat(AT_FDCWD, "/sbin/pivot_root", [{tv_sec=1691413782, tv_nsec=0} /* 2023-08-07T13:09:42+0000 */, {tv_sec=1691413782, tv_nsec=07264a8db6415: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:7144f7bab3d4c2648d7e59409f15ec52a18006a128c733fcff20d3a4a54ba44a
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
[pid   223] pivot_root(".", "." <unfinished ...>
                                                [pid   223] <... pivot_root resumed>)   = 0
                                                                                           1
0592bac28743:/#
```